# Determinar si una hora está entre dos horas dentro de un rango de horas

Tags: java, android

Actualmente utilizo este método para determinar si una hora esta dentro de un rango por ejemplo:

> Hora actual: **14:00**,  Hora Inicial: **11:00**,  Hora Final: **15:00**

```
public boolean Comprobar(String dActual, String dInicial, String dFinal) throws ParseException {
      Date actual = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").parse(dActual.trim());
      Date inicial = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").parse(dInicial.trim());
      Date final = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").parse(dFinal.trim());
      if(actual.after(inicial) && actual.before(final)){
          return true;
      }
      return false;
}
```

Utilizando el ejemplo anterior el resultado es el correcto: `true`.

Pero al intentar comparar una hora que se encuentre entre la noche y la madrugada por ejemplo:

> Hora actual: **23:00**,  Hora Inicial: **22:00**,  Hora Final: **01:00**

El resultado que da es `false` aunque en el ejemplo, las 23:00hrs si se encuentra entre las 22:00hrs y las 01:00hrs.

¿Cómo podría determinar correctamente si la hora actual está dentro del rango?

#### Edición 1:

El margen de comparación es de 24 hrs, iniciando a las 6:00hrs de un día y finalizando a las 6:00hrs del siguiente tomando diferentes horarios en comparación con la hora actual, ejemplo:

```
06:00 - 12:30

12:30 - 06:00

06:00 - 22:00

22:00 - 03:00 << Rango de horas entre días

03:00 - 06:00
```

Comment: El algoritmo no esta mal, mas bien no te funciona, ya que estas asumiendo que 1:00 esta en el dia siguiente y to código no lo considera asi. Necesitas agregar la fecha a tus fechas para que funcione como deseas

Comment: Te aconsejo coger fechas y horas con LocalDate y LocalTime. Tienen diversas funciones para restar fechas y horas entre dos elementos del mismo tipo y un parse para pasarle horas y fechas.

Comment: Necesitas añadirle al algoritmo la información de que si la hora inicial es mayor que la hora final, entonces la hora final se refiere al día siguiente. Es algo que una persona entiende instintivamente pero que en el algoritmo se tiene que especificar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### La solución que buscas:

Si la hora de fin es menor que la de inicio, parece ser que asumes que la hora de fin corresponde al día siguiente:

```
if (dateFinal.before(dateInicial)) { // Nota: Siempre usa nombres de variables descriptivos, nada de a, b, c..
   dateFinal = new Date(dateFinal.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // 1 día en milisegundos
}
return dateActual.after(dateInicial) && dateActual.before(dateFinal);
```

Esto soluciona el ejemplo propuesto

#### La solución correcta:

Como comenta Dani, trabajar con tiempos es complicado. Aquí asumes un caso, pero ignoras los demás. ¿Qué pasa si inicio es 23:00, fin es 01:00, y actual es 0:30? ¿Es 0:30 en el mismo día de inicio (fuera de rango) o en el mismo día de fin (en rango)? ¿Cómo se decide a que día corresponde cada hora?

Igual en tu contexto específico tiene sentido hacer una serie de asunciones sobre lo que significa cada hora y a que día pertenece en función de su valor, pero deberías tener cuidado en tener claro que asunciones haces y dejarlas reflejadas (al menos en la documentación), de lo contrario vas a tener constantemente resultados incorrectos cuando esas asunciones no se cumplan.

Si quieres una función general, tendrás que tener en cuenta que lo que comparas no son "horas" sino instantes en el tiempo, y esos instantes de tiempo incluyen la información del día.

Si tu método tiene la información para convertir "horas" a instantes en el tiempo, debes incluir la lógica necesaria en el método para hacer esa conversión correctamente. Si no la tiene, tu método debe exigir que se le pasen instantes de tiempo (por ejemplo como Date) y que sea el código cliente el que se encargue de calcular qué instantes se evalúan según la información de que disponga.

Comment: Además, al hacer la conversión de horas a instantes parte de la lógica del método, lo haces menos reutilizable (no puedo usarlo para hacer el cálculo de si las '19:24 01/01/1991' está entre las '19:00 01/01/1991' y las ' 20:00 01/01/1991', o sí una hora está en el próximo fin de semana.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, mi margen de comparación es entre 2 días, iniciando a las 6:00hrs de uno y terminando a las 6:00hrs del siguiente, así, que el margen es de 24hrs donde el cambio solo se ve reflejado en el incremento de un día a la fecha.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (c.before(b)) { // el caso especial
    return a.after(b) || a.before(c);
}
else {             // el caso normal
    return a.after(b) && a.before(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Los nulos y las fechas han sido siempre un dolor de cabeza en programación. No sé para qué necesitas comparar esas horas, pero yo me buscaría una estrategia para poder compararlas sin meterme en mucho rollo.

Por ejemplo, si requieres sólo la hora porque, por ejemplo, los empleados entran a las 10 de la noche y salen a las 6 de la mañana, podrías sumar dos horas a las horas de entrada y salida (o más por si alguien llega antes de la hora), y podrás compararlas sin problemas, ya que en tu programa entrarán a las 0 horas y se irán a las 8 horas.

Las horas, minutos y segundos por sí mismos no te valen para comparar tiempo, porque el tiempo es cíclico. Podrías decir que las 3 están entre las 2 y las 4 o no, dependiendo de los días del calendario a los que pertenezcan. Mañana tendrás la misma hora, minuto y segundo que hoy, al igual que lo tuviste ayer. Y pasa lo mismo con la fecha si no le incluimos el año.

Por lo que la solución más sencilla sería usar la clase Date. Ésta ya tiene métodos para poder consultar si una fecha es mayor o menor que otra. En el caso de ejemplo que he puesto podrías generar una fecha Date y compararlas por ejemplo de ésta forma:

```
if(empleado1.getHoraFichaje().after(fechaEntrada)) { 
     echarBroncaEmpleado(empleado1);
}
```

Buscando en la red, he visto que tienes otro hilo sobre ésto [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237193/how-to-convert-currenttimemillis-to-a-date-in-java) y formas más variadas. Eso sí, en inglés. Espero haberte echado una mano.

Un saludo.

Comment: La idea del principio es bastante acertada, pero la solución propuesta no aporta nada (de hecho el código de la pregunta ya está usando `java.util.Date`)

Comment: Muy buena lógica con otros casos que podrían suceder, acabo de editar mi pregunta, el rango que intento comparar esta solo entre 2 días, aunque tomaré en cuenta cuando la comparación se haga entre varios días diferentes.

Comment: Faltan datos, te lo he dicho. No se puede calcular y te lo dije antes, porque el tiempo es cíclico. Prueba a programarlo y te darás cuenta.

Comment: Y lo digo porque lo he intentado, y si la hora inicial es mayor que la final (como en el caso que has puesto de 22:00 - 3:00), puedes sencillamente sumar 24 horas a la hora final para no tener problemas de que la hora final sea menor que la inicial, pero al no tener la hora incial y final del periodo del que hablas, no sé si debo o no sumar esas 24 horas a la hora actual.

Comment: @SJuan76 Es cierto que usa la clase Date, pero quiere usar sólo horas y minutos. Por qué no ampliar a usar todo su potencial? Tiene métodos y más valores que le podrían solucionar los problemas de forma más sencilla. 
Desde mi punto de vista es una pregunta sin sentido. Si estás usando la clase Date, úsala y no obvies una parte de esa clase que le daría la solución a tus problemas.